# Excel VBA How does Excel sort duplicate values?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I'm wondering how Excel would sort identical values. I have ID numbers, but there are instances where there would be a duplicate ID number. I'm unsure about how Excel would decide how to order these? Would it just look at the information in the adjacent row and then compare those values as part or the ordering?

If I had:

```
Column A | Column B
166          C
166          A
166          B
```

And then sorted on Column A in descending order, would I get:

```
Column A | Column B
166          C
166          A  
166          B
```

Or would I get:

```
Column A | Column B
166          A
166          B
166          C
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can add extra columns as tie breakers if you want. But in the absence of that, the order of rows with equal values is essentially random. The sort is **unstable**.

Comment: While I don't know the answer, I assume it would just read columns left to right.  But you'd be wise to be explicit and specify a 2nd column if you care about it.

Comment: @pnuts - even more of a bother than typing out this well thought out question! :)

Comment: I don't think Excel uses information in adjacent columns unless you specifically tell it to by adding those to the "sort" columns defined via the UI dialog.

Comment: spreadsheet and database sorts are usually stable. Adjacent cells not specified for the sort are ignored when comparing rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel's sort is supposed to be a stable sort, so the order of equal elements should be preserved. You should be able to do something similar to radix sort, sorting rows doing multiple sorts, from least significant column to most significant column. You can sort rows by 3 columns at a time.

If using Visual Basic to do the sort, note that selection sort and quick sort are not stable. Use insertion sort (stable) or bubble sort (stable) instead. I don't know if it's possible to implement merge sort (stable) with VBA.

A non-stable sort can be made stable by including the row number in a compare as the least significant comparator, if this is possible with VBA.

Comment: _...so the order of equal elements should be preserved_: sounds reasonable (and is supported by a quick test.)  Do you have an authoritative reference to support this claim?

Comment: @chrisneilsen - microsoft example for [how to sort rows by more than 3 columns](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/268007). Spreadsheet and data base sorts are usually stable sorts.

Comment: Excel ALWAYS performs stable sorts.

Comment: VBA QuickSort is not stable

Comment: And lots of other sorts aren't either. But sorting from the UI is.

Comment: what's the meaning of stable in this context? if only one field is selected as the key to sort then how do you expect excel (or anyone) to differentiate between several cells with exactly same value, what other order to use?. The reason for someone to think that something is not correct is when compares the order of these same values adding other fields to the picture. The point is why someone arrives to the conclusion that something is wrong with the sort instead of that needs to add those fields to the sort key? if expects them to be consider when sorting...

Comment: @EEM - wiki article [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts) .

Comment: @rcgldr thanks for the link. I got the concept now. However, at the end it only comes to what the request is, if only one key is included then all other fields are out of scope, that's the primary decision, on the contrary if they matter then they should be included in the sort key.

Comment: precisely that article implies that excel sort is stable.. also that's is I believe in excel 2007 later versions have much more keys, but even then what I used to do was to create a "sort field" concatenating the fields values in the order needed.

Comment: @EEM - My impression is that stable sorts have been used in spreadsheet programs going at least back to 1985 (like SuperCalc2, Lotus 123, Excel, ...) .